# How to I modify an external list?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to code this thing in python, and I have bumped into a road block. I have this list, and I want to modify it, and keep the changes after the program is exited. I have no clue where to start.

Essentially, I want a list that can be accessed and modified, and will be saved and not reset after the thing using it is closed.

EDIT: Here is my idea; There is a list that I have, let's call it basket.
I want to code a program to add to and remove from the 'basket', and to keep the changes after I close the program. Hope that clarifies... And I tried using global, but that got all funny, so I essentially deleted that version.

Comment: You need to provide the code you have tried.

Comment: Please post your code it will be useful to recognize your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json, pickle, or any similar library to write data to a file and  read it back and store in a list. This will create the file save.json in your current working directory that contains json-information about your list. You will notice that your list will always contain the numbers you added before, it doesn't "forget" what you added to the list since it's saved in a file.

```
import os
import json

foo = [1,2,5,9] #default

#if safe file exists, load its contents into foo list
if os.path.isfile("save.json"): 
    with open("save.json", "r") as file:
        foo = json.loads(file.read())

foo.append(int(input("Enter a number to add to foo")))
print(foo)

#write foo list to file
with open("save.json", "w") as file: 
    file.write(json.dumps(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with an external file.

Simply write the list to a file, and later this information can be retrieved, manipulated as a list and then overwritten.

As far as I am aware, there is no other way of persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started in plain python. The example includes a way to save a list to a file and a way to read from the file. Since you didn't provide any code you have tried it will be your job to work this out the way you need it to be.

```
#saving a list to a file
items = ['apple', 'pear', 'grape']


file = open('C:\PythonTest\somefile.txt', 'w+')
for item in items:
    file.write('%s\n' % item)

file.close()


#reading a list from a file
items = []
with open('C:\PythonTest\somefile.txt') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        items.append(line.rstrip("\r\n"))
print(items)
```